# How portable is relying on sizeof for structures without padding

Tags: c++, serialization, padding, sizeof

In code I have to maintain, some array serialization (e.g. `std::vector<T>`)
happens roughly the following way: there is an `array_t` structure without
padding:

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
template <typename T, uint32_t N>
struct array_t
{
    typedef T value_type;
    static uint32_t const max_length = N;

    uint32_t length;
    value_type data[max_length];

    value_type const & operator[](uint32_t k) { return data[k]; }
    value_type & operator[](uint32_t k) { return data[k]; }

    template <typename Container>
    void from_container(Container const & c)
    {
        std::copy(c.begin(), c.end(), &(*this)[0]);
        length = c.size();
    }

    template <typename Container>
    Container to_container() const
    {
        return Container(&(*this)[0], &(*this)[length]);
    }
};
#pragma pack(pop)
```

And when such datatypes need to be sent over the network, what happens is
(very simplified):

```
template <typename T>
char * serialize(T const & data)
{
    void * buf = std::malloc(sizeof(T));
    std::memcpy(buf, &data, sizeof(T));
    return reinterpret_cast<char *>(buf);
}

std::string const s("This is some string");
typedef array_t<char, 64> arr_str;
arr_str serial;
serial.from_container(s);
char * buf = serialize(serial);
network.send(buf); // frees the memory as well
```

And on the other end this method is called:

```
template <typename T>
T deserialize(char * ptr)
{
    T data;
    std::memcpy(&data, ptr, sizeof(T));
    std::free(ptr);
    return data;
}

arr_str deserial = deserialize<arr_str>(buf);
```

We do not need to argue that this is not the best way of serializing
objects. What concerns me now: how portable is that? The comments of these
methods say that this is guaranteed to work on every x86/x64 system - is
that claim true?

Comment: Check what size the involved types have (size_t, T etc.) and most likely you will find out that they differ in size.

Comment: @PlasmaHH `sizeof(char)` is `1` on every platform I worked on so far, and the structures are limited to `bool` and the `intxx_t` and `uintxx_t` types - so that shouldn't be a problem

Comment: I see a `size_t` there.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes You're right, but that differs from the implementation and happened while stripping everything to a minimal example. I fixed that now.

Comment: @nijansen: there is a size_t. also outside of the x86 family CHAR_BIT might not be 8, and intX_t types are optional and may not exist everywhere. Not to talk about endianess issues.

Comment: @nijansen: There is no guarantee that the `intXX_t` and `uintXX_t` exists in all platforms or that they have the same exact size. For example, some DSPs don't have types smaller than 32 bits, so when targeting the DSP, `int16_t` might be 32bits. Alignment might not be important in one platform and structures might default to packed... it all depends on how *portable* you want *portable* to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is definitely not portable to "any x86" architecture, unless you take very good care to use only types that are defined size (`uint16_t`, `uint32_t`, etc) in ALL of the data structures that you are using.

Obviously, if you go OUTSIDE of the x86 family of processors, then you have the further problem of byte-ordering.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is vague.  If the same binary is doing the transmission and receiving, and the data type T is POD, then this will work.

If different binaries are used - compiled with different compilers, compiler versions, compiler settings etc., then simple types and simple structures of data types may be ok (compile-time offset_of and sizeof assertions are worth consideration), but many things are not specified by the Standard, including the way bit fields are ordered and padded (particularly when they cross 8/16/32-bit boundaries), the size of bools and enums (unless specified as per C++11).  The layout of a lot of Standard library types isn't specified either, so you can't assume that say a std::string would survive the transmission even if you knew both sender and receiver used short-string optimisations for the string size involved.